# what is the difference between Cycle and circuit

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithm, cycle, transitive-closure

I have confusion that what is the differnce between the two ?

Cycle and circuit so  please make me sure by diagrams if possible.

what i have in mind is that the cycle is always in undirected graph the circuit is always a directed graph. please correct me if i am wrong ?

Comment: @ Adel Khayata Do you have answer for this question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@blgt There is some difference , I found it finally.

The circuit is on directed graph and the cycle may be undirected graph.
whereas the path can be differntiated by cycle and circuit by the point that path start from u vertex  and may end at v vertex.(starting point and end point are not same) and it may even repeat the same vertex again but not the case with circuit.
see this link for more information-
http://www.esiee.fr/~coustyj/EnglishMorphoGraph/L3.pdf (i prefer to give the link in order  to make it helpful for future refrence)

Answer (score 5):

A cycle  is  a closed  path.  A path  is  a  walk  with  no  repeated  vertices.
Circuits  refer to  the  closed  trails.
Trails  refer  to  a  walk  where  no  edge  is  repeated.

Comment: Illustration of the difference is given here: http://www.edmath.org/MATtours/discrete/concepts/cwalk.html

Answer (score 0):

There's no official and/or widely accepted definition of a **difference** between `cycle` and `circuit`.

Most literature I've seen uses them interchangeably; if it doesn't: you should expect it to define this somewhere in its glossary of terms (if it has one).